# Bundle error using webpack for Electron application `Cannot resolve module 'electron'`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I am trying to create an *Electron* application with *React*. I use *Webpack* to compile the *React JSX* syntax, but when I try to compile with `webpack` command, I got this error:

> ERROR in ./app.jsx
> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'electron' in /Users/masterT/Downloads/gist
>
> @ ./app.jsx 6:18-37

Here is the [application code](https://gist.github.com/masterT/56891033a25b6114c839).

I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Just a note, you don't need webpack to use JSX with Electron. Simply use the [Babel require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) in an early entry point in your app. [My boilerplate](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/react-babel-boilerplate) shows how to do this with Babel version 5 instead of 6.

Comment: ^ This no longer is a good solution because contextIsolation=true and nodeIntegration=false is preferred. So renderer process doesn't have access to Node.js environment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Webpack tries to resolve `electron` module with the installed node_modules. But the `electron` module is resolved in Electron itself at runtime. So, you have to  exclude particular module from webpack bundling like this:

webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: './built',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  target: 'atom',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel',
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: [
    (function () {
      var IGNORES = [
        'electron'
      ];
      return function (context, request, callback) {
        if (IGNORES.indexOf(request) >= 0) {
          return callback(null, "require('" + request + "')");
        }
        return callback();
      };
    })()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Great answer! Really appreciate!

Comment: this is useful, and although it works, it isn't specific to the question unlike Konrad's answer below

Comment: Superb!! I was having the error `Can't resolve 'fs' in '.....node_modules\electron'` and adding the excludes fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 37):

A very simple solution :

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
```

webpack will ignore this require

Comment: nice one ! I don't need to touch the webpack config and it's perfect for me because my environment could be web or electron

Comment: why is everyone using complicated webpack configs when this simple solution works? are there any drawback?

Comment: It works when developing, but after packaged the electron app it doesn't work anymore, any suggestion?

Comment: Won't work with ESM source. The `externals` solution below is better.

Answer (score 25):

You can set `target: 'electron'` in your webpack config and then you don't have to exclude electron in externals.

From [webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target):

> `"electron"` Compile for usage in [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) – supports `require`-ing Electron-specific modules.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it's the only one that addresses the specific issue.

Comment: It seems that this doesn't stop webpack from compiling electron requires into bundle.js. It doesn't throw error - yes - but you will have a broken bundle js with node module copied in it if you'll attempt to require any node-only modules in your jsx's ("path" for ex). At least that what i've experienced using "electron-main" and/or "electron-renderer" targets ("electron" target is depreciated in latest). Seems like using window.require for electron requires works and allows for more control.

Comment: Note that in newer Webpack versions, the correct target name is `electron-main`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: [ nodeExternals(), 'react', 'electron' ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the above examples, but none of them seemed to work for me.
I then installed `Electron` using npm and then used `yarn build`
It worked and I got my production build.

`npm i electron`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31448155)

Answer (score -3):

Your package.json has 'electron-prebuilt' but you require 'electron' in your code. Have you tried require-ing 'electron-prebuild'?

Comment: If you look at the [quick start](http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/) in the *Electron* documentation, they `require('electron')`. I think the problem is related to webpack.

Comment: if you perform > "npm ls electron" in your terminal, does it list anything?

Comment: It returns `└── (empty)`. But in my code, **electron** is not a reference to this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron, it's a reference to https://github.com/atom/electron.

Comment: I see, so it must be a webpack config; I indeed some rather diferent webpack configuration for `target` going on here: https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.development.js although `target: 'atom'` is what's in the webpack doc, as you've probably found. It's using https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer to finish configurering webpack it seems.

Comment: Well it worked using the module https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer, but why it didn't work using option `target: 'atom'`? It feels wrong to use a module when there is supposed to be a **built-in** solution in *webpack*. Don't you think?