# Cannot find module 'electron' in Electron + React + Webpack setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I am using React + Electron + Webpack to create an application, but while trying to use Electron modules, i am getting the error stating "Cannot find module 'electron'.

I have the below sample code in one of my React components :-

```
const shell = window.require("electron").shell;
shell.showItemInFolder("C:\\Logs");
```

I have referred many of the issues which were raised in SO related to webpack & Electron, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

When i try the below code :-

```
require('electron-prebuilt')
```

It returns me back the path to the electron executable.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427446/bundle-error-using-webpack-for-electron-application-cannot-resolve-module-elec

Answer (score 0):

There is a `target` option in webpack's configuration, you need to set it to `electron`. Like this:

```
var config = {
    target: 'electron',
    entry: __dirname + '/main.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    ...
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

In webpack, you can set the development targets. By default, the target will be set to web. So you need to set the target as `electron-renderer` in the renderer processes and `electron-main` in the main process.

```
//In the renderer configuration
module.exports = {
 target: 'electron-renderer',
 //... other configurations
}

//In the main configuration
module.exports = {
 target: 'electron-main',
 //... other configurations
}
```

`electron` and `atom` are alias for electron-main