# How to use Native Node Modules in angular running in electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, node-modules

**Problem description:**
This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427446/bundle-error-using-webpack-for-electron-application-cannot-resolve-module-elec) Question. I'm not trying to access the electron module (I use a [electron wrapper for angular](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron) to do this), I'm trying to use a npm native module in angular while running angular inside electron.

**Original description:**
I have an angular app which I run with electron (A new app, doesn't do anything yet).
To access Bluetooth I use [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) and [bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno) but while they are working from within electron (to test this I added, `noble = require('noble')` to index.js in the electron folder) they do not work when I add for example noble to the app.compoents.js in angular.

**This is my app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title: String = 'Colaboration room';
    noble = require('noble')

}
```

**I get this error:**

> WARNING in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js 76:43-53 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

While this is only a warning, the angular initial page is no longer displayed ( its empty).

**Question:**
How can I access node native modules in Angular (when running in electron)?

**Additional Information:**
Im using angulars default compiler `webpack`
The native modules are build against the node version from electron
with [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild).
I use the `ngx-electron` module to access the electron api from within angular, thus my guessing that I cant just access noble from within angular without some modification.

**Folder structure**

[image]

**Solution attempt:** (Since I'm new to node and Angular, I'm happy for code improvements !)

Since I use [a wrapper](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron/) to access electrons apis I had no problem with the electron module.
My real problem was that I didn't know how to access native node modules in angular.

One possible solution is to [add the native npm module to webpacks script part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j) (I did not test this yet).
The other solution is to use require in electrons main.js and set it as a 
global variable.

```
const noble = require('noble');

global.sharedObj = noble;
```

You can then access this global variable using electrons api with the [angular electron wrapper](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron/).

```
getBluetoothCentralPulgin(){
  var es = new ElectronService();
  return es.remote.getGlobal('sharedObj');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bundle error using webpack for Electron application \`Cannot resolve module 'electron'\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427446/bundle-error-using-webpack-for-electron-application-cannot-resolve-module-elec)

Comment: okay I will check that

Comment: @estus I do not have a not found problem and I can build angular with electron, my question is about node native modules build against the node version from electron and why I cant use them in angular

Comment: You have to exclude the modules that shouldn't be bundled by Webpack with `externals`. Or try to use `window.require` to skip them from bundling too. That's what the answers suggest.

Comment: hm, would it still be possible to package them with electron ? When I do not bundle them, how can I use them ? ( I'm new to node)   I will try that and report back.

Comment: Node-specific modules should not be bundled with Webpack but reside in node_modules .

Comment: @estus Okay I understand that, but my question is then about how to access native modules in angular and is therefore not a duplicate of the linked question. See my solution attempt which hopefully clarifies this. If there is however something fundamentally wrong in my understanding, please tell me.

Comment: You access them by either disabling bundling for server side modules with `externals` or using them with `window.require` instead of `require`. This is what the answers say. I'm unable to confirm if this works for Angular application. See also https://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron

Comment: I read the answer and tried that yesterday but I still got the same error. Anyway the above solution worked for me in angular.

Comment: angular cant access the system while running inside electron, the noble module has a bindings script which needs the os module. I guess thats why I get the warning.